# It's possibile to integrate Uncss on my own server?

Tags: php, css, serverside-javascript

It's possibile to integrate Uncss on my own server to load only the necessary css on every page ?

Comment: Yes, but it would probably be hideously slow to run and make your CSS inefficient due to the loss of caching benefits.

Comment: I'm working on E-commerce website and the purpose is to load the least possible css